# Error: Duplicación / Triplicación de registros en tabla al guardar en Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, vue.js

devs!
Antes de más nada, muchas gracias a todos de antemano.
Tengo un sistema hecho en Laravel + Vuejs + Axios, que registra turnos de pacientes a la base de datos, y en el momento de guardar, tengo 4 tablas, donde en cada una se registra solamente 1 registro, pero el problema que tengo, es que cuando se guarda, (Solamente algunas veces), ocurre que se duplican los registros, a veces triplican, y cierta vez llegó a generar 6 repeticiones. 
Cuando se duplica, ocurre que en las 4 tablas, ocurre la misma cantidad de duplicaciones, es como si hubiera un for insertando varias veces el mismo registro en cada tabla, (usando ids deferentes). mas abajo les muestro el código de cada parte.

Frontend, requisición axios con vuejs.

```js
 axios
  .post("/api/turno/add", [
    this.disponibilidades[indexDoctor],
    this.especialidad,
    this.pacienteSelected,
    this.getSituacion,
    horario,
    this.especialidadObj,
    this.calendario,
    this.turno
  ])
```

routes/api.php (Por donde pasa el request)

```html
Route::post('turno/add', 'HomeController@addTurno');
```

Laravel Backend, función que guarda

```js
 public function addTurno(Request $request)
    {

        $guardar = true;
        $mensajeError = [];

        // Verificar si el paciente ya ha reservado un turno en el dia
        $cantidadTurnosPaciente = Paciente::verificarCantidadTurnoPaciente($request[2]['pac_codigo'], $request[6]);



        $hoy = date('Y-m-d');
        $manana = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+1 day'));

        if (!($request[6] == $hoy || $request[6] == $manana)) {
            $guardar = false;
            $mensajeError[] = "La fecha seleccionada es diferente de hoy o mañana";
        }

        if ($cantidadTurnosPaciente[0]->cantidad > 0) {
            $mensajeError[] = 'El paciente seleccionado ya tiene un turno registrado para esta fecha';
            $guardar = false;
        }

        if ($guardar) {

            try {
                DB::beginTransaction();

                $tmpDoctorEspecialidad = Paciente::verificarDoctorEspecialidad($request[0]['e_doctor'], $request[1]);
                $turno = $request[7];




                if ($turno == 0) {
                    $hora = date('H');
                    if ($hora < 12) {
                        $turno = 2;
                    } else {
                        $turno = 3;
                    }
                }

                $tmpNumero = Paciente::getNumero($request[0]['e_doctor'], $request[1], $turno, $request[6]);
                $tmpOrden = Paciente::getOrden($request[0]['e_doctor'], $request[1], $turno, $request[6]);

                $regTurno = RegistroTurno::create([
                    'r_fecha' => $request[6],
                    'r_hora' => $request[4],
                    'r_paciente' => $request[2]['pac_codigo'],
                    'r_especialidad' => $request[1],
                    'r_doctor' => $request[0]['e_doctor'],
                    'r_turno' => $request[0]['dis_turno'],
                    'r_numero' => $request[5][0]['simbolo'] . $tmpNumero[0]->nro,
                    'r_nro_orden' => $tmpOrden[0]->nro,
                    'r_atendido' => 0,
                    'r_estado' => 1,
                    'r_disponibilidad' => $request[5][0]['discodigo']
                ]);



                $consulta = Consulta::create([
                    'con_sucursal' => 1,
                    'con_operador' => 1,
                    'con_paciente' => $request[2]['pac_codigo'],
                    'con_seguro' => $request[2]['pac_seguro'],
                    'con_fecha' => $request[6],
                    'con_hora' => $request[4],
                    'con_moneda' => 1,
                    'con_doctor' => $tmpDoctorEspecialidad[0]->e_codigo,
                    'con_tipo' => 1,
                    'con_cobertura' => 0,
                    'con_descuento' => 0,
                    'con_importe' => 0,
                    'con_observacion' => 'Consulta Rapida - WEB',
                    'con_atendido' => 0,
                    'con_estado' => 1,
                    'con_valor' => 0,
                    'con_saldo' => 0,
                    'con_numero' => $tmpOrden[0]->nro,
                    'con_nroorden' => $request[5][0]['simbolo'] . $tmpNumero[0]->nro,
                    'con_consultorio' => $request[0]['consultoriocod'],
                    'con_seguroestado' => $request[3],
                    'con_terminal' => 'WEB'
                ]);

                $turnoConsulta = TurnoConsulta::create([
                    'c_turno' => $regTurno->r_codigo,
                    'c_consulta' => $consulta->con_codigo,

                ]);



                $turnoOcupado = TurnoOcupado::create([
                    'to_fecha_actual' => date('Y-m-d'),
                    'to_hora_actual' => date('H:i:s'),
                    'to_fecha' => $request[6],
                    'to_doctor_id' => $request[0]['e_doctor'],
                    'to_turno_id' => $regTurno->r_codigo,
                    'to_paciente_id' => $request[2]['pac_codigo'],
                    'to_horario' => $request[4],
                    'to_estado' => 1
                ]);


                Paciente::findOrFail($request[2]['pac_codigo'])->update(['pac_celular' => $request[2]['celular']]);


                DB::commit();
                $estadoMsg = $this->sendMessage($request[2]['pac_documento'], $request[2]['nombres'], $request[6], $request[4], $request[0]['nmbres'], $request[0]['consultoriodes'], $request[2]['celular']);
                return response()->json([$consulta, $regTurno, $turnoOcupado, $estadoMsg], 201);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                DB::rollBack();

                $mensajeError = $e;

                return response()->json([
                    'status' => 'error',
                    'msg'    => 'Error',
                    'errors' => $mensajeError,
                ], 422);
            }
        }


        return response()->json([
            'status' => 'error',
            'msg'    => 'Error',
            'errors' => $mensajeError,
        ], 422);
    }
```

Resultado en algunos momentos, ejemplo de una de las tablas, pero en todas ocurre la misma cantidad de duplicaciones

[image: Ejemplo de 6 repeticiones del mismo registro en una de las tablas. (En las demás tablas ocurre la misma cantidad de repeticiones). El campo estado fue alterado para dejar solamente un registro (como debería ser)]

La aplicación está en un servidor, y la base de datos utilizada está en un servidor externo, y por lo menos 10 a 15 usuarios utilizan ese mismo sistema al mismo tiempo, pero no veo el por qué de ocurrir esas repeticiones de registros... y solamente en ciertos momentos...
Si alguien ha pasado por algo similar o tenga alguna idea de como poder resolver, agradecería mucho.

Obs: En el localhost no ocurren esas repeticiones, he probado varias veces... Solamente ocurre en el servidor, apuntando a ese servidor externo. La conexión a veces es un poco lenta al momento de entrar.

Comment: ¿No será que el usuario está apretando muchas veces el botón de "guardar"?¿ O que tienes algo en el código javascript que hace que esa llamada axios se ejecuto muchas veces?

Comment: No creo que sea esto, porque estoy utilizando SweetAlert, y cuando das click en confirmar, ya cierra la ventana y espera la confirmacion de Laravel, ademas que cuando confirma, se hace una serie de validaciones en laravel, que es guardado como false en la variable guardar. Validaciones como> Este paciente no tenga mas de una consulta en el mismo dia, que ese doctor no tenga mas de una consulta en el mismo horario en el mismo dia... Lo mas raro es que solamente en ciertas veces ocurre...

Comment: a mi me pasa lo mismo en servidor de digital ocean y en hostgator. Y nunca encuentro la solución.